# .Net Core Web api return just based props

Tags: json, api, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

```
public ActionResult LoginGet([FromBody]PostHelperEntity<Sw_User_LoginDto> helperEntity)
{
   var result = _service.GetSingle(x => x.UserName == helperEntity.Entity.UserName  && x.Password == helperEntity.Entity.Password);
   return Ok(result);
}
```

My actionresult is like this, its returning data correctly in result.
But when i use return Ok(result).
Its returning just based props.

Here is result;

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "createDateTime": null,
        "updateDateTime": null
    },
    "listData": null,
    "success": true,
    "message": null
}
```

result variable have name and surname columns.

if i use

```
 return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

data returned correctly in postman.

ResultVariable

[image]

postmanResult

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with _just based props_?

Comment: coming props from inherited(base) class.

Comment: @MarkusSafar i added pics.

Comment: @batuhanaslantürk What is the problem? Do you have any errors. Can you post a json you are expecting>

Comment: @Serge look ResultVariable ss there is name and surname columns and look postmanResult there is no name and surname.

Comment: @batuhanaslantürk You have to post SW_UserDto class

Comment: @Serge i cant, that is generic structure, i have main controller. That must be return baseclass type. (im sorry for my bad english :/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for base structures,

Add this nuget;

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

then add these codes to your program.cs or startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Now im getting all props.